# Ho good is this optimization to heapsort by dividing into 2 parts

Tags: heap, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I was thinking about quicksort not finding the exact midpoint for pivot.
Any effort to find exact midpoint as pivot slows down quicksort & is not worth it.

So is it possible to accomplish that using heapsort & is it any worthwhile?
I selected heapsort because it can find next max/min in logarithmic time.

If we divide heapsort array into 2 parts.

```
1) In the left half, we find max heap. (n/2-1 comparisons)
2) In the right half, we find min heap. (n/2-1 comparisons)
3) While 
     (max in left half is < min in right half){
      -- swap max in left half with min in right half
      -- heapify the swapped elements in respective halves 
      (i.e. find next max in left half 
       & find next min in right half).      
       } 
    end while loop.
```

When this loop  ends, we have two completely disjoint halves.
There is no improvement so far than regular heapsort.

1) We can complete the remaining heapification in each half (log n/2 for remaining elements at most). 
So any element that was in the correct half would heapify log n/2 at most instead of log n at most.

This is one optimization

The other optimization can be

2) We may be able to recursively apply this in each disjoint half (divide & concur). 
3) Also we can exclude the central 2 elements from subsequent disjoint partitions, because they are already in their invariant location
e.g. 1-16 (n-1 comparisons to find max/min)
we have 1-7 & 8-16 partition in the first step 
second step may have  4 partitions
(7 & 8  are in invariant location) (so n-3 comparisons to find max/min)
3 step may have 8 partitions
with 4 more more elements in invariant location.
So n-7 comparisons to find max/min in each partition.

I am trying to implemented this, 
But I would like to know if anybody sees any theoretical advantage in this approach or it is no good.

For already sorted, I see there will be no swapping & we just go on finding max/min in subsequent halves
For descending sort, we see all elements getting swapped & heapified with no chance to divide & concur. So it will be as good or as bad as normal heapsort. this may be the worst case.

For all others, we will see any any improvement after max/min swapping stops.

Comment: The simplest way to know (because exact analysis looks tremendous): benchmark your algorithm against Heapsort. My bet: always slower.

Answer (score 0):

You have an O(n) pass that creates two heaps. Then in the worst case you have `(n/2)*(log n/2)` replacements in each of the two heaps. At this point you've already done `n*log(n/2)` operations, and you haven't even started sorting. You will require another `n*log(n/2)` operations to finish the sort.

Contrast that to heapsort, which has the O(n) pass that creates a single heap, and then n*log(n) operations to complete sorting the array.

I see no particular advantage to building two heaps of size n/2 rather than a single heap of size n. In the best case you have more complicated code that has the same or worse asymptotic complexity, and is unlikely to give you a real-world increase in performance.

Comment: The worst case scenario where array is already sorted in Descending order or all elements in second half are larger than all in first half, we will move all n elements in one step. but we are also heapify() ing them which means they are sorted. So we should be done sorting in 1 step itself. We may need to keep a check for that. That makes it n*log(n) worst case. The thing is

Comment: Thanks. 
I think the worst case behavior where all elements get shuffled in 1 step,
we have already completed the sorting. 
(since we take min from right and heapify it in left & vice versa)

One issue I see is:
With 2 heaps, we lose track of how may elements go shuffled & where the went.
I see it performs O(log2(n)) iterations  or  if we exclude central elements
But work done in each iteration performs O(log2(n) -1) * (O(n) + heapify())
The only hope is heapify itself is sorting partially.
So if more work is done in one step, we might find that next does very little work..

Comment: @WinterMelon You say, "but we are also heapify() ing them which means they are sorted." Building a binary heap is not the same thing as sorting. Spreading the work across multiple smaller heaps isn't going to change the total amount of work being done.

Comment: I agree. Sorry about that. Heapify() is giving only the max and not sorting. So I don't see anything better in this approach. .

Comment: @WinterMelon Heapify does more than give only the max. It arranges the array so that it is in heap order. That's not sorted, but it's not random. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap.